# Can't get accepts_nested_attributes_for to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models, A `Workout` and a `WorkoutEquipment`.

```
class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :exercise
  belongs_to :session
  belongs_to :workout_equipments

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :workout_equipments
end

class WorkoutEquipment < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :workout
  has_many :equipment

end
```

My /new looks like this:

[image]

And the form behind that looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@workout) do |f| %>
  <% if @workout.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@workout.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this workout from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @workout.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>


  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :exercise_id %><br>
    <%= f.select :exercise_id, Exercise.all.collect{|t| [t.name, t.id]}, {prompt: true} %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :session_id %><br>
    <%= f.select :session_id, Session.all.collect{|t| [t.when, t.id]}, {prompt: true} %>
  </div>

    <%= fields_for(:workout_equipment) do |u| %>
        <div class="field">
        <%= u.label :equipment_id %><br>
        <%= u.select :equipment_id, Equipment.all.collect{|t| [t.name, t.id]}, {prompt: true} %>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
        <%= u.label :equipment_weight %><br>
        <%= u.number_field :weight %>
        </div>
    <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

However, when I submit, despite the `accepts_nested_attributes_for :workout_equipments`, the `workout_equipments.id` is not being placed into the `workout` object.  The output log looks like this:

```
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by WorkoutsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"âœ“", "authenticity_token"=>"OSh3xA+usL4/0MAtvRqKio2Vcz/ziLdQ1Rj2vh5zLCXxlVhofoCGh88ssEn+IOc2AXhn3sXWsZn3bIO93hyJMA==", "workout"=>{"exercise_id"=>"4", "session_id"=>"3"}, "workout_equipment"=>{"equipment_id"=>"4", "weight"=>"9001"}, "commit"=>"Create Workout"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "workout_equipments" ("equipment_id", "weight", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["equipment_id", 4], ["weight", 9001.0], ["created_at", "2016-01-27 02:56:56.611731"], ["updated_at", "2016-01-27 02:56:56.611731"]]
   (6.1ms)  commit transaction
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "workouts" ("exercise_id", "session_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["exercise_id", 4], ["session_id", 3], ["created_at", "2016-01-27 02:56:56.640104"], ["updated_at", "2016-01-27 02:56:56.640104"]]
   (7.4ms)  commit transaction
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
```

As you can see, only `exercise_id` and `session_id` are being recorded.
My relevant controller actions are the following:

```
def create
    @workout_equipment = WorkoutEquipment.create(workout_equipment_params)
    @workout = Workout.create(workout_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @workout.save
        format.html { redirect_to @workout, notice: 'Workout was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @workout }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @workout.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

def workout_equipment_params
      params.require(:workout_equipment).permit(:workout_id, :equipment_id, :weight)
end

def workout_params
      params.require(:workout).permit(:exercise_id, :session_id, :workout_equipments_id)
end
```

Is there something else I have to do for the `params` methods?

Answer (score 2):

In your model, the belongs_to & accepts_nested_attributes_for methods should take `:workout_equipment` (note it's in the singular, not plural, form)

```
    class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base

      belongs_to :exercise
      belongs_to :session
      belongs_to :workout_equipment

      accepts_nested_attributes_for :workout_equipment
    end
```

In your controller, you don't need to build a workout_equipment object because `nested_attributes` does that for you:

```
    def create
        @workout = Workout.create(workout_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @workout.save
            format.html { redirect_to @workout, notice: 'Workout was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @workout }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @workout.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
    end
```

By the same token, you don't need `workout_equipment_params` and should enrich your `workout_params` method:

```
    def workout_params
          params.require(:workout).permit(:exercise_id, :session_id, workout_equipment_attributes: [:id, :workout_id, :equipment_id, :weight])
    end
```

I may have misunderstood the attributes you have in each of your models so modify the params accordingly.  In general, you'd be sending the nested_attributes into a `workout_equipment_attributes` hash.

Good luck!

Comment: This code is completely error-free and looks sensible, however it's not working.  This makes me wonder if in fact there is something I'm expecting out of `accepts_nested_attributes_for` that it doesn't offer.  Should I be using the `build` method here?  Doing so indicates that `workout_equipment_id` is unkown, despite it being an accepted attribute.  This could be because without a `WorkoutEquipment.create()` , while an object is being created, it is not being inserted into the database, and thus no id is being generated.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your association names (you're using `plural` when it should be `singular`):

```
#app/models/workout.rb
class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :workout
   belongs_to :session
   belongs_to :workout_equipment
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :workout_equipment
end

#app/models/workout_equipment.rb
class WorkoutEquipment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :workouts
end

#app/controllers/workouts_controller.rb
class WorkoutsController < ApplicationController
   def new
     @equipment = Equipment.all
     @workout = Workout.new
     @workout.build_workout_exercise
   end

   def create
     @workout = Workout.new workout_params
     @workout.save
   end

   private

   def workout_params
     params.require(:workout).permit(workout_exercise_attributes: [:equipment_id, :weight])
   end
end

#app/views/workouts/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @workout do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :workout_exericse do |w| %>
     <%= w.collection_select :equipment_id, @equipment, :id, :name %>
     <%= w.number_field :weight %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I wasn't aware there was a `collection_select`, thank you for identifying that!  Unfortunately the `build_workout_equipment` isn't accepting the nested `workout_equipment_attributes`, namely the `workout_equipment_id` despite its inclusion in my permitted parameters.  I've fixed the plurality of my models as well.

Comment: Can you show us the parameters that are being sent by your form?

Comment: Sure, It's actually there in the console log that I posted, those are still the attributes being shown on error pages, browser console, and webrick console.  `"workout"=>{"exercise_id"=>"4", "session_id"=>"3"}, "workout_equipment"=>{"equipment_id"=>"4", "weight"=>"9001"}`

Comment: Looks like the fields_for method isn't working properly

Comment: Do you think so?  It seems as though it's accomplishing what it's supposed to do, right?  Should I use `@we = WorkoutEquipment.create` and then call `fields_for(@we)` - as in do you think it's not tying its values to anything?

Comment: when you use `fields_for`, you should expect the params `_attributes` to be passed. Not having this suggests you either don't have the associative object built or invoked.

Comment: Sorry, could you be a little more specific?  Is  `_attributes` a suffix for the model - as in `workout_equipment_attributes`?  Do you mean passed from the controller to the form or from the form to the `.build`?

Comment: Yep, when you have a `fields_for` instance, it should compile the params as `[[association_collection]]_attributes` - if it doesn't, it means you have either not built the object in the `new` method, or don't have `accepts_nested_attributes_for` set up correctly

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but I can't produce that effect.  When you say `accepts_nested_attributes_for` could be set up incorrectly, how do you mean?  It seems like a one-liner should be (but obviously isn't) no fuss, so is there something I could have screwed up with the model association?  I only have the models, views, and controllers as possible problem areas, but I still can't seem to isolate the issue :/  I'll try to update the question with as much relevant information as I can.